# Open shell script from Finder interactively

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

I am running my manual backups with a shell script that asks me for a password. However, when I open the script from the Finder, it terminates immediately.

How can I get a script to run interactively when double clicking on it in Finder?

Comment: PS. `set -i` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a bash script to work from finder, it has to have the `.command` extension

For example, I created the following script to use `sudo` to ask for a password and then to output a welcome message, then "wait" to simulate execution time:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "Welcome to Ask Different"
sleep 10
exit 0
```

I saved it as `test.command`.  You also have to make it executable:  `chmod +x test.command`

Here's the result of clicking on the script:

[image]

Comment: Turns out, the Terminal setting 'Close if shell exited cleanly' does not keep the window open if the script exited non-zero. Entirely different problem. The `.command` part does not seem to make any difference at all. So, mea culpa, should have worked perfectly fine in the first place, if I hadn't been so stupid 